# ms-access built in function Month(number)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I Have been playing with variations of the Month... function in access query builder.  I am having trouble building a date value from an expression.  I am looking to create my own date that will be behind the scenes to perform some filtering and other tasks.  My problem is that I cant seem to get the Month(number) function to do what I think it should be doing. Here is a summary of what I am looking for.

```
5/31/2012
```

Through something like this

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(5),Day(31))
Also
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month("5"),Day("31"))
```

When I try these as an experssion the return is

```
1/30/2012
```

Im sure I am misunderstanding the structure.  Please educate me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateSerial requires three integers, year, month, day:

```
 DateSerial(1992,5,2)

 02/05/1992 ''Euro locale
```

Year(Date()) returns an integer, so you can substitute:

```
 DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,31)
```

Interestingly, the zeroth day is the last day of the previous month:

```
 DateSerial(2012,12,0)=30/11/2012
```

-- http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/HV080206953.aspx

As an aside, do not forget that all dates are numbers.

`Month(5)` will equal 1, but `Month(41263)=12` !

Also

```
?month(100)
 4 
?Year(100)
 1900
```

Comment: Remou, so the DateSerial works off a sequential day value not calendar value. So March 10, 2012 is equivalent to Month(130)???

Comment: No. A year integer, a month integer between 1 and 12 and a day integer between 1 and 31. I included a link. However, you can mess about and get a result, just not the result you expected. The additional information is to do with the fact that all dates are numbers. 41263 is today, so the month is 12.

Comment: Thanks Remou! I appreciate your assistance!