# ms-access 2003 DateSerial Function Overflow Error

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ms-access built in function Month(number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979943/ms-access-built-in-function-monthnumber)

In one of my queries I have the following function.

```
DateSerial(Date(),[Roster]![DOH],[Roster]![DOH])
```

When I invoke the query I receive an overflow error.  What am I doning wrong?

Comment: The users Date of hire. stored in a linked table as Date/Time with an input mask of 99/99/0000;0;

Comment: DateSerial(integer,integer between 1 and 12, integer between 1 and 31) **not** DateSerial(date,date,date). We went through this and I posted a link to the MS help page.

Comment: I used the link and must not have properly understood the material. I will review again.  Thanks,

Comment: That previous question was about `Month()`; this one is about `DateSerial()`.  Calling them duplicates seems overly aggressive with your close vote.

Comment: While the question may have a different title, the subject matter is identical. From your previous vehement defence of your stance, I thought you did not wish to have people answer poor and duplicate questions.

Comment: @HansUp I tend to agree but I think the both questions might just be *I don't understand how DateSerial works somebody help* and Remou's last answer should have been sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `[DOH]` is date of hire and you want the anniversary in the current year, use this:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month([Roster]![DOH]), Day([Roster]![DOH]))
```